# vim: execute shell command with variable and redirect output to new buffer

Tags: windows, vim

I want to call msbuild from the function below and redirect the output to a new buffer.

My problem is that I need to use a variable, for the filename, and therefore cant use '!' (can I?), and when I use exe or system() read complains that I'm not giving it a proper file.

```
func! myFunction()
    let findstr = "findstr /s /m " . '"' . expand("%:t") . '"' . " *.vcxproj"
    for project in split(system(findstr), nr2char(10))
        echo "Building '" . project . "'"
        let msbuild = "c:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\msbuild.exe" . " " . project . " " . "/t:rebuild /p:configuration=debug"
        :tabnew | r system(msbuild) "<--THIS LINE HERE
    endfor
endfunc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:read` command takes a file not a vim expression. However it can read in from standard output via `:read !{cmd}`. Example `:%r!ls`. Using the `:execute` command you can build your new command with your variable.

```
exe '%r!' . msbuild
```

Or you can use `:put` along with the expression register if you want to use an expression like `system()`. (Probably want to follow this with `:0d_` to delete the first empty line)

```
put=system(msbuild)
```

Now it looks like you are trying to build your project and get a list of errors. I would recommend you look into `:make`, the `'makeprg'` option, and the `quickfix` list as this is a more vim way of building a project.

For more help see:

```
:h :r!
:h :exe
:h :pu
:h @=
:h :make
:h 'makeprg'
:h quickfix
```

Comment: Brilliant, I tip my hat to you, good sir!
Followup question: what does the '%' in "exe '%r!'" do?

Answer (score 0):

This is a function you can use to execute arbitrary shell commands and present their output in a new window ( you can put this in your _vimrc):

```
let s:lastcmd = ''
function! s:RunShellCommand(cmdline, bang)
    " Support for repeating last cmd with bang:
    let _ = a:bang != '' ? s:lastcmd : a:cmdline == '' ? '' : join(map(split(a:cmdline), 'expand(v:val)'))

    if _ == ''
        return
    endif

    let s:lastcmd = _
    let bufnr = bufnr('%')
    let winnr = bufwinnr(_)
    " You can position the new window whenever you want, I chose below + right:
    silent! execute  winnr < 0 ? 'belowright new ' . fnameescape(_) : winnr . 'wincmd w'
    " I could set buftype=nofile, but then no switching back and forth buffers.
    " The results are presented just for viewing, not editing, modify at will:
    setlocal buftype=nowrite bufhidden=wipe nobuflisted noswapfile wrap number

    setlocal modifiable
    silent! :%d
    " Useful for debugging, if you encounter issues with fnameescape():
    call setline(1, 'You entered:  ' . a:cmdline)
    call setline(2, 'Expanded to:  ' . _)
    call append(line('$'), substitute(getline(2), '.', '=', 'g'))

    silent execute '$read !' . _
    silent! execute 'autocmd BufUnload <buffer> execute bufwinnr(' . bufnr . ') . ''wincmd w'''
    " If resizing is unwanted for commands with too much output, remove this line:
    silent! execute 'autocmd BufEnter  <buffer> execute ''resize '' .  line(''$'')'
    " You can use <localleader>r to re-execute the last command:
    silent! execute 'nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <localleader>r :call <SID>RunShellCommand(''' . _ . ''', '''')<CR>'

    execute 'resize ' . line('$')

    setlocal nomodifiable
    1
endfunction " RunShellCommand(cmdline)
command! -complete=shellcmd -nargs=* -bang Shell call s:RunShellCommand(<q-args>, '<bang>')
```

Use like:

```
:Shell gcc -ggdb -o test test.c && ./test
```